# How to create a color dict for multiple items from a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, colors, plotly

I have over 40 or so unique items in a dataframe column (e.g. 'a','b','c'......). I want to create a colour dictionary without having to type something like the following. So that each unique item has a unique colour - How can i create a dictionary like below which would enable me to give a unique colour to each item.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    color_discrete_map = {'a':'rgb(42,9,4)', 
                              'b':'rgb(111,203,209)',
                              'c':'rgb(55,165,172),',
                              'd':'rgb(29,127,136)',
                              'e':'rgb(2,84,92)',
                              'f':'rgb(4,37,42)',
#....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, just grab a list of colours then join along the axis.

e.g

```
df_colors = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebrainz/color-names/master/output/colors.csv',header=None)

df_colors.columns = ['color_name', 'color_description', 'hex_value', 'r', 'g','b']
```

---

```
print(df_colors)

          color_name      color_description hex_value    r    g    b
0    air_force_blue_raf   Air Force Blue (Raf)   #5d8aa8   93  138  168
1   air_force_blue_usaf  Air Force Blue (Usaf)   #00308f    0   48  143
2  air_superiority_blue   Air Superiority Blue   #72a0c1  114  160  193
3       alabama_crimson        Alabama Crimson   #a32638  163   38   56
4            alice_blue             Alice Blue   #f0f8ff  240  248  255
```

---

assuming your dataframe has unique values then you can just join along the indices.

```
print(df)

  name
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d

df1 = df.join(df_colors[['r','g','b']].astype(str).agg(','.join,axis=1).to_frame('rgb'),how='left')

print(df1)

  name          rgb
0    a   93,138,168
1    b     0,48,143
2    c  114,160,193
3    d    163,38,56
```

---

if you specifically want a dictionary, you can zip then after creating two iterables.

```
n = df['name'].unique()

c = df_colors[['r','g','b']].astype(str).agg(','.join,axis=1).tolist()

dict(zip(n,c))

{'a': '93,138,168', 'b': '0,48,143', 'c': '114,160,193', 'd': '163,38,56'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`seaborn.color_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.color_palette("husl", 10) # 10 colors
```

[image: seaborn palplot]

The returned object contains tuples with the RGB values:

```
>>> list(sns.color_palette("husl", 10))
[(0.9677975592919913, 0.44127456009157356, 0.5358103155058701),
 (0.8616090647292522, 0.536495730113334, 0.19548899031476086),
 (0.6804189127793346, 0.6151497514677574, 0.19405452111445337),
 (0.46810256823426105, 0.6699492535792404, 0.1928958739904499),
 (0.20125317221201128, 0.6907920815379025, 0.47966761189275336),
 (0.21044753832183283, 0.6773105080456748, 0.6433941168468681),
 (0.2197995660828324, 0.6625157876850336, 0.7732093159317209),
 (0.433280341176423, 0.6065273407962815, 0.9585467098271748),
 (0.8004936186423958, 0.47703363533737203, 0.9579547196007522),
 (0.962272393509669, 0.3976451968965351, 0.8008274363432775)]
```

*NB. 40 colors is a lot for the human eye to be able to discriminate all, but have a look at the options of the method, there are may possibilities*

other examples.

"Set2":

[image: Set2]

"Paired":

[image: Paired]

Finally, an example of how to construct a dictionary:

```
dict(zip(list('ABCDEFG'), [tuple(int(c*255) for c in cs) for cs in sns.color_palette("husl", 7)]))
```

output:

```
{'A': (246, 112, 136),
 'B': (197, 147, 49),
 'C': (130, 168, 49),
 'D': (52, 175, 137),
 'E': (55, 170, 186),
 'F': (128, 150, 244),
 'G': (244, 93, 235)}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### One approach:

```
dict(zip(df.columns, colors))
```

#### Example output:

```
{'a': 'rgb(0.0, 0.0, 255.0)',
 'b': 'rgb(127.5, 0.0, 127.5)',
 'c': 'rgb(255.0, 0.0, 0.0)'}
```

In `dict(zip(df.columns, colors))`, `df.columns` is a list of column names, and `colors` is a list of colors that you can define very much as you'd like. Your use case is not completely clear to me, but it's hard to go wrong with a scale of some sort. And using plotly's [`n_colors`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.colors.html) you can easily build `n` colors between, for example, `red` and `blue` like this:

```
colors1 = n_colors('rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', len(df.columns), colortype='rgb')
```

This will work fine for almost any number of colors. If you've got a limited number of colors, you can always select one of the many [plotly color](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/) schemes available, for example like this:

```
colors2 = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet[:len(df.columns)]
```

#### Color samples:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.colors import n_colors

# sample dataframe
np.random.seed(1234)
colnames = list('abcdefgh')
data = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(1, len(colnames)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.columns=colnames


# plotly figure
fig1 = go.Figure()

# add markers with colors from colors_dict1
colors1 = n_colors('rgb(0, 0, 255)', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', len(df.columns), colortype='rgb')
colors1
colors_dict1 = dict(zip(df.columns, colors1))

for i, k in enumerate(colors_dict1.keys()):
    fig1.add_traces(go.Scatter(x= [i], y = [1], mode ='markers',
                               marker_color = colors_dict1[k],
                               marker_size = 20,
                               showlegend = False))

# add markers with colors from colors_dict1
colors2 = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet[:len(df.columns)]
colors2
colors_dict2 = dict(zip(df.columns, colors2))

for i, k in enumerate(colors_dict2.keys()):
    fig1.add_traces(go.Scatter(x= [i], y = [2], mode ='markers',
                               marker_color = colors_dict2[k],
                               marker_size = 20,
                               showlegend = False))

fig1.show()
```